# Unity Turn Animation Parameter (float) Keeps Resetting to Zero Making 3rd Person Character Walk Forward Again

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, parameters, game-physics

My character can walk forward, but when I hold down "w" (forward) and "a" (left) and then release "a" he returns to walking in the original direction that forward was facing.

It is as if the controls make him walk according to a compass. Each WASD key turns him to the same direction each time, W being north, and S being south, no matter his orientation.

I noticed my Turn parameter, which is a float, starts to move when I turn, but slowly resets to zero turning my character back to that north direction. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure what you meant but this is how I make my player move***

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float walkSpeed;
    public float runSpeed;
    public float turnSpeed;
    void Update()
    {
        invControl = GetComponent<InventoryController>();
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            WalkForward();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            RunForward();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            WalkBack();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            RunBack();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            TurnLeft();
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
       TurnRight();
        }      
    }
    void WalkForward()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void WalkBack()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void RunForward()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void RunBack()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void TurnLeft()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void TurnRight()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using `Input.GetAxis()` for controlling your character (like most people), which resets to 0 whenever you're not pressing the keys associated with it. This is what's causing your turn parameter to reset.

I would presume whatever code you have to control the player is flawed. I can't help you further because you didn't post any code.